# Jmeter Distributed testing - unable to connect the remote (slave systems)

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter Distributed testing - unable to connect the remote (slave systems)
I am getting the below error
"non-JRMP server at remote endpoint"
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an incorrect setup of [RMI ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote), JMeter master tries to connect to the slave machine using the hostname or IP address and port which is specified in the `remote_hosts` property or passed via [`-R` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options).

The error means that something else, not JMeter's RMI registry is running on machine 192.168.0.103 on port 1099.

So you need to connect to your slave machine and check what's listening on port 1099 using [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) or equivalent and either terminate that application or amend JMeter configuration to use different port.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: now i can able to connect in both master and slave. But for me first master is running and the result is came on the listener. After few mins only the slave is get executing and that too finished but  that result is not showing in the master machine listener.